# Extract time from timestamp in teradata while dropping seconds and milliseconds

Tags: sql, timezone, timestamp, teradata, truncate

I am trying to convert a timestamp formatted like the following example, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff', to just the time in hours and minutes. I will be using this field later as a grouping dimension so it's important that the seconds and milliseconds are dropped. I would prefer that the result value still be interpreted as true time it is not required so if I were to get a string I would be okay. Lastly and most important the timestamp is in UTC time and I need it to be converted to American eastern.

Any assistance with this would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: 1) Search first, you will probably find your questions have already been answered.  2)  StackOverflow is not a coding service where you can just say what you want and someone will make it for you.  3) Show what you have tried and what didn't work.  4) Don't ask two questions in a single post.  5 ) Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry there Matt. Since I was having issues with converting a single field I didn't think I need to provide a thesis. Thank

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp formatting in Teradata is kind of a pain, in my opinion, and some of this stuff is poorly documented.

For timezone conversion in Teradata, use `<TSCOLUMN> at <difference from UTC>`. So for EST:
`<TS COLUMN> at -5`.  (At least I think EST is UTC -5.)

For your desired format, you have to leave it as a char column.  Teradata won't let you have a timestamp column with no seconds. So, based on your example format above:

`cast (<TS COLUMN> at -5  as char(16))`

EDIT:
As pointed out, using a hour difference for tz conversion isn't a very good idea.  You can use `AT <TZ NAME>`, as listed in this [Teradata link](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/ch07.077.013.html).  So, for eastern you would use:

`<TS COLUMN> AT 'America Eastern'`.

Since it's currently DST, that will currently return a 4 hour difference.

Comment: US Eastern Time is only in EST (-5) during the winter months.  In the summer, it's EDT (-4).  Hardcoding a -5 is not a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract the seconds:

```
ts - (extract(second from ts) * interval '1.000' second)
```

And then subtract 5 hours to adjust for EST:

```
ts - (extract(second from ts) * interval '1.000' second)
   - interval '5' hour
```

To cast the timestamp to a string you need to apply a FORMAT:

```
cast(cast(ts as format 'yyyy-mm-ddBhh:mi') as char(16))
```

Or Oracle's TO_CHAR in TD14:

```
to_char(ts, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

Edit:
When you need to apply daylight savings you should use

```
(ts - (extract(second from ts) * interval '1.000' second))
   AT 'America Eastern'
```

Of course this will change the datatype to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, but you need the time zone information anyway. time zone

Comment: US Eastern Time is only in EST (-5) during the winter months.  In the summer, it's EDT (-4).  Hardcoding a -5 is not a good plan.